# Missing Key value pair in Tree Map

Tags: scala, treemap

I'm trying to solve a programming problem using TreeMap, which led me to post this question.

I have a defined a treeMap with (Int,Int) as my key and String as the value, defined the treeMap ordering on the basis of the first element of the tuple.
and I have inserted two elements different Key, but the final treeMap contains only one element.Is this the defined behaviour of treeMap

Scala Code: (Version: 2.12.3)

```
val a = scala.collection.mutable.TreeMap[(Int, Int), String]()(Ordering.by(x => x._1))
a.put((9, 21), "value-1")
a.put((9, 10), "value-2")
println(a.size) // 1
```

I have tried the Same implementation in java, but it reports the Map Size as 2
here is my java code:

Can Some one suggest if i'm missing some thing

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class JavaTreeMapTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        class Tuple {
            Integer a;
            Integer b;

            public Tuple(Integer a, Integer b) {
                this.a = a;
                this.b = b;
            }

        }
        Comparator<Tuple> testComparator = new Comparator<Tuple>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(Tuple arg0, Tuple arg1) {
                if (arg0.a > arg1.a) {
                    return arg0.a;
                } else
                    return arg1.a;
            }

        };

        TreeMap<Tuple, String> tm = new TreeMap<Tuple, String>(testComparator);
        tm.put(new Tuple(100, 100), "value-1");
        tm.put(new Tuple(100, 101), "value-2");

        System.out.println(tm.size()); //2

    }
}
```

Comment: `Ordering.by()` is unneeded because the natural order of `Tuple2[Int,Int]` is already `_1`. The secondary order key is `_2`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To give a precise answer, I would say that, unlike Java's `TreeMap`, `scala.collection.mutable.TreeMap` uses the provided `Ordering` to determine equality rather than using `==`. This has some other interesting consequences. Using the `a` from your question:

```
a.contains((9, 0)) // true
a((9, -1000)) // "value-2"
```

Indeed, Ordering has a method [`equiv`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/math/Ordering.html#equiv(x:T,y:T):Boolean) for determining whether two things are equal in an ordering. While this method is not used in the [TreeMap implementation](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.0/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/RedBlackTree.scala#L39), it shows the philosophy of relying on the `Ordering` as the source of truth rather than the less flexible `==`.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is with your ordering. If you use it like this: `Ordering.by(x => x._1)`, TreeMap will consider only first element for calculating equality.
So, both `(9, 21)` and `(9, 21)` would be considered equal.

One solution would be to order first by first element and then by second. You can do this by returning a tuple:
`Ordering.by(x => (x._1, x._2))`.

But since you're already using tuples, you can simplify it to:

```
Ordering.by(x => x)
```

or

```
Ordering.by(identity)
```

or

You can omit it because ordering by identity is a default.

To wrap up:

```
val a = scala.collection.mutable.TreeMap[(Int, Int), String]()
a.put((9, 21), "value-1")
a.put((9, 10), "value-2")
println(a.size) // 2
```

Comment: I think you mean "for both (9, 21) and (9, *10*)" and "the key will be *`9`*". Also, it would be more accurate to say that TreeMap treats `(9, 21)` as equal to `(9, 10)` under that ordering; the key in the Map is not actually 9, as you can determine by calling `.keys` on the map. (Though there's some awkward overloading of terminology here, since 9 is the key in the Ordering, but not the Map...)